# Jest + Vue test utlis TypeError: Cannot set property 'content' of null

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I am writing a test on a Vue project, and I am new to Framwork Jest and Vue testing utilities, have not found solutions to similar issues, have tried with multiple components but the error is still similar, I thought about Mock axios, it didn't work, if someone can help me I'm stuck,
if someone can offer me a solution or have an idea how it goes, it will be perfect

Api.js

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import qs from 'qs';
import router from '@/router';
import defaultExport from '@/store';

let apiBaseUrl = document.querySelector('meta[name="apiBaseUrl"]');
if(!apiBaseUrl) {
    apiBaseUrl.content = '/api/';
}

let newAxios = axios.create({
    headers: {
        // A fix for IE11 - we need to define Pragma header
        Pragma: 'no-cache',
        // 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    },
    withCredentials: true,
   //baseURL: apiBaseUrl.content,

    paramsSerializer: function (params) {
        return qs.stringify(params)
    }
});
```

Login.vue

```html
<script>
  ****
        data() {
            return {
                currentMode: "login",
                passwordForgotMode: false,
                registerMode: false,
                email: "",
                password: "",
                rememberMe: false,
                emailRules: [
                    v => !!v || 'E-Mail wird benötigt',
                ],
                passwordRules: [
                    v => !!v || 'Passwort wird benötigt',
                ],
                valid: false,
            }
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters({
                isAdministrator: 'account/isAdministrator',
            })
        },
        methods: {
            ...mapActions({
                handleLogin: 'account/handleLogin',
                addSnackbarFromError: 'app/addSnackbarFromError',
            }),
            send() {
                if (this.$refs.form.validate()) {
                    this.handleLogin({
                        rememberMe: this.rememberMe,
                        email: this.email,
                        password: this.password,
                    })
                        .then(() => {
                            window.localStorage.setItem('logged_in', true);
                            if (this.$route.query.redirect) {
                                this.$router.push(decodeURIComponent(this.$route.query.redirect));
                            } else {
                                if (this.$store.getters["account/isAdministrator"]) {
                                    this.$router.push({name: 'userNotificationsOverview'});
                                } else {
                                    this.$router.push({name: 'startingSite'});
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            this.password = '';
                            this.addSnackbarFromError(error)
                        })
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Test.test.js

```js
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import Login from "@pages/Login";


let wrapper;
let store;
let actions;
let mutations;
let state;
const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(Vuex);

beforeEach(() => {
    actions = {
        someAction: jest.fn()
    };
    mutations = {
        someMutation: jest.fn()
    };
    state = {
        key: {}
    };
    store = new Vuex.Store({
        actions,
        mutations,
        state,
    });

    wrapper = shallowMount(Login, {
        propsData: {},
        attachTO: '#root',
        mocks: {},
        stubs: {},
        methods: {},
        store,
        localVue,
    });
});

afterEach(() => {
    wrapper.destroy();
});

describe('Component', () => {
    test('is a Vue instance', () => {
        expect(wrapper.contains('h2')).toBe(true)
    });
});
```

```
● Test suite failed to run

 TypeError: Cannot set property 'content' of null
let apiBaseUrl = document.querySelector('meta[name="apiBaseUrl"]');
       7 | if(!apiBaseUrl) {
    >  8 |     apiBaseUrl.content = '/api/';
         |     ^
       9 | }
      10 |
      11 | let newAxios = axios.create({
```

Answer (score 0):

The bug is here:

```js
if(!apiBaseUrl) {
   ^^^^^^^^^^^
    apiBaseUrl.content = '/api/';
}
```

The `!apiBaseUrl` condition checks that `apiBaseUrl` is falsy (`null` or `undefined`), and then tries to use it, leading to the error you observed.

Simply remove the `!` operator from the condition to fix that error:

```js
if(apiBaseUrl) {
    apiBaseUrl.content = '/api/';
}
```

Comment: I have tried but I still get the same error  !!

Comment: That seems highly unlikely with the code shown in the question, given that there's only that one reference to `apiBaseUrl`. Can you share a link to a reproduction?